# ¿Cómo devolver el mismo código de la función en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero una función en `javascript` que haga cualquier cosa y además devuelva, por ejemplo con un `alert()`, el mismo código de la función.

```
<script>
    function return() {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = red;
         *"instrucción para que devuelva el propio código"*
         }
</script>
```

Esa función debería cambiar el color del background y devolverme el propio código de la función.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "devolver el propio código"? ¿Devolver un *string* con el código?

Comment: @Darkhogg Sí, eso mismo quería. Necesitaba la función toString().

Answer (score 14):

Tienes que utilizar `toString()`, que aplicado sobre una función devuelve el código fuente de la misma.

```js
function soyLaFuncion() {
    var cuatro = 2 + 2;
  
    alert(soyLaFuncion.toString());
}

soyLaFuncion();
```

Comment: Era eso, precisamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @RodrigoPérezLópez si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar calle para obtener el la función que se esta desencadenando.
Esta propiedad pertenece a arguments que es un objeto (array like object) que es pasado con parametro implicitamente en todas las funciones, este contiene todos los argumentos con los cuales fue invocada la funcion (en este caso "alerta").
Recuerda que una función en javascript se puede invocar con menos, iguales o mas parámetros que los que esta especifica que recibe.

```
function alerta() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        alert(arguments.callee.toString());

    }
alerta();
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Así la función te devolvería como un string del código dentro de si misma:

```js
    
    //Definición de mi función
    function miFuncion() {

        //Operaciones varias dentro de tu funcion
        var retultadoDeOperacion = 5 + 5;
      
        //Aqui retorna el codigo dentro de si misma
        return miFuncion.toString();

    }
    
    //Ejecutamos la función dentro de un alert para ver el código.
    alert(miFuncion());
```